# Modem manager GUI does not work

Tags: 18.04, internet, usb-modem, modem, modem-manager

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I usually use a Huawei E3131 dongle to connect to the Internet. Recently I wanted to read the SMS messages and run USSD codes to communicate with the ISP to control my data package. So I installed Modem Manager GUI. It did exactly what I expected without any errors. But, suddenly I noticed that the modem manager GUI does not start anymore. I removed it completely and re installed it. but no change. It does not work. My Internet connection is OK and can connect to the Internet. Can you help me to get the Modem manager GUI to work? or any alternatives?

Comment: The same with me. When starting from cli I get the message "double free or corruption (out) [...] SIGABRT". It simply doesn´t start anymore. Yet up to now it used to work.

Comment: @Rosika no error messages for me, when I click the icon it shows it is trying to open at the activities on the top bar, but then nothing happens.

Comment: In the meantime I contacted the developer of ModemManager via e-mail. My question was: `Is it possible that the new version of ModemManager could be responsible for this? Might there be any incompatibilities? His ANSWER:

This is possible. We need to investigate this.`
Please post a bug report on modem-manager for that. Thanks/

Comment: @Rosika thank you for the news.